# Actions and nested goal states

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings. Since it is possible that a array is a data structure for an action goal, I would assume that more complex data structures may also be possible. I would like to give my action server a list of poses so it can calculate and execute a path.

How can I define a nested data structure inside my action in order to hold the poses?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410809/actions-and-nested-goal-states/) by [NotARobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/69326/notarobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2022-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can nest message types inside message types, service types and action types in both ROS1 and ROS2.

See section 2.1.1 of [the documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Concepts/About-ROS-Interfaces.html)

See [a tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Single-Package-Define-And-Use-Interface.html#extra-use-an-existing-interface-definition)

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2022-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3